# Need to show date in primeng bar chart

Tags: javascript, angular, bar-chart, primeng

I'm using primeng along with Angular to show bar chart/graph. In the below code, I want to display date like (27-feb-23) on X axies. I guess, I need to add some labelformat in ticks, though I'm not sure. If someone knows how to display barchart using primeng, please let me know. As of now bar is looking like this.
[image]

```
    export class BarGraphComponent {
      basicData: any;
    
        basicOptions: any;
    
        chartOptions: any;
    
        horizontalOptions: any;
    
       
    
        constructor() {}
    
        ngOnInit() {
            this.basicData = {
                labels: ['Set Pre-Cast Girders-San Antonio OC-Stage 1 - Milestone', 'Pour Footing-6th OC-Bent 2-Stage 1 - Milestone', 'Setup MOT-Monte Vista UC-Stage 2B - Milestone', 'Open Campus Bridge For Traffic - Milestone', '  Place JPCP-Benson To Mountain (Sta 1093-1125)-Stage 2A WB (GP#3 & 4 & SH) - Milestone', 'Excavate Bench 5th-RW 1155 (SHGA) - Milestone', 'Form Superstructure Face-RW 1154 (Soldier Pile & GA) - Milestone'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'My First dataset',
                        backgroundColor: '#42A5F5',
                        data: [ new Date('2023, 2, 27'), new Date('2023, 2, 27'), new Date('2023, 3, 1'), new Date('2023, 3, 6'), new Date('2023, 3, 26'), new Date('2023, 4, 11'), new Date('2023, 4, 26')]
                    }
                ]
            };
    
    
    
            this.horizontalOptions = {
                indexAxis: 'y',
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        labels: {
                            color: '#495057'
                        }
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        ticks: {
                            color: '#495057',
                            
                        },
                        grid: {
                            color: '#ebedef'
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
                        ticks: {
                            color: '#495057'
                        },
                        grid: {
                            color: '#ebedef'
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
    
    
          
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass an option input for that p-chart and define there the ticks callback like this:

```js
chartOptions = {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            callback: (label, index, labels) => {
              return label + '%';
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```